# How do I load a remote JSON file in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I'm pretty much a complete beginner to Swift. I've played around with SwiftUI a bit, but that's about it. Needless to say, I have no idea how classes, structs, protocols, and everything else works in Swift.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to load a JSON file into Swift, and I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I would think that such a thing would be fairly rudimentary for such a modern language, but apparently not. After trying multiple tutorials and examples, I've come up with this messy code:

```
public class JSONReader {
    struct DatabaseObject: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let books: AnyObject
        let memoryVerses: AnyObject
    }
    private func parse(jsonData: Data) {
        do {
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(DatabaseObject.self, from: jsonData)
            print(decodedData)
        } catch {
            print("decode error")
        }
    }
    private func loadJson(fromURLString urlString: String,
                          completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                
                if let data = data {
                    completion(.success(data))
                }
            }
            urlSession.resume()
        }
    }
    init() {
        loadJson(fromURLString: "Redacted for privacy") { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let data):
                    self.parse(jsonData: data)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the buildtime error `Type 'JSONReader.DatabaseObject' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

Any help, pointers, or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you ask a question about parsing JSON it is good practice to include a block with an example of the JSON you are intending to parse. That way we can guide you to the dasta structure that would fit your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `AnyObject` is not decodable by swift , The books property you are trying to decode and memoryVerse are not decodable , If you want to Decode this you can define their types separately as codable structs like so

```
struct Book : Codable{
    let property : String
    let otherProperty : String
}
struct Memory : Codable{
        let property : String
        let otherProperty : String
    }

struct DatabaseObject: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let books: Book
        let memoryVerses:Memory
    }
```

Comment: Gotcha! So I need to make a strict for each object property as well, basically. Thanks! I’ll try it when I get home and make sure to mark you as correct!